# Como ajustar o Time Zone do Mysql?

Tags: mysql

Eu peguei um projeto antigo no github, e o projeto se tratava de uma aplicação JSF que estava usando o artefato do mysql antigo como podem ver abaixo;

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.25</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
```

e estava gerando erros, e pelo que entendi deveria mudar para a versão compatível com a versão que eu estava utilizando no meu banco de dados, então fui verificar a versão do meu comando com o comando;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então troquei por esse artefato;

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.11</version>
        </dependency>
```

Quando submeti meu formulário me deparei com um erro 500 em tela do navegador, e quando fui checar o log de erros no meu eclipse encontre resumidamente esse erro;

> Caused by:
>   com.mysql.cj.exceptions.InvalidConnectionAttributeException: The
>   server time zone value 'Hora oficial do Brasil' is unrecognized or
>   represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the
>   server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property)
>   to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone
>   support.

Então se tratava de ajustar o fuso horário do mysql, porém como fazer isso? eu fiz minhas tentativas e não conseguir, **é por isso que estou pedindo ajuda!**

Eu fiz essas tentativas

[Como ajustar o fuso horário ou timezone no MySQL](https://elias.praciano.com/2015/07/como-ajustar-o-fuso-horario-ou-timezone-no-mysql/)

[Como configurar o fuso horário do MySQL por nomes.](https://elias.praciano.com/2015/07/como-configurar-o-fuso-horario-do-mysql-por-nomes/)

Com o comando `SELECT @@time_zone;` deu esse resultado abaixo;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então eu alterei executando esse comando;

```
SET @@global.time_zone = '+3:00';
QUIT
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

eu tentei executar o comando `SET time_zone='America/Sao_Paulo';` mas deu comando incorreto.

Depois disso executei novamente a aplicação e ela funcionou normalmente, porém ao reiniciar o computador e tentar tudo de novo voltou a ficar com o problema.

**Por favor, gostaria que alguém pudesse me explicar como ajustar corretamente o fuso horário para eu não ter problemas em executar minhas aplicações.**

Answer (score 4):

Acabei de resolver.

No arquivo persistece.xml estava assim

```
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/boleto"/>
```

Mas agora está assim;

```
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/boleto?serverTimezone=UTC"/>
```

Depois da alteração funcionou perfeitamente.